# VBA VLOOKUP, instead of 'book1', as a string

Tags: excel, vba

EDIT: Posted full userform code

[this is my userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuIkf.png)

What I need to do, is load a csv, and a second csv essentially with updated price. I'm then using vlookup to match data. I just cant get my code to compile while I try to target MyVal2 with Module3.

Book1 is a remnant from recording a macro testing how it'd work.

```
Public MyVal1 As String 'AUS URL'
Public MyVal2 As String 'scrape'


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=(MyVal1)
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=(MyVal2)
Application.Run "Module2.AuscompDataSheet"
Application.Run "Module3.AuscompDataSheet"

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close


End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()


    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With fd

      .AllowMultiSelect = False

      ' Set the title of the dialog box.
      .Title = "Please select the file."

      ' Clear out the current filters, and add our own.
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

      ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
      ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
      ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
      If .Show = True Then
        TextBox1 = .SelectedItems(1)

      End If
   End With
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()


    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With fd

      .AllowMultiSelect = False

      ' Set the title of the dialog box.
      .Title = "Please select the file."

      ' Clear out the current filters, and add our own.
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

      ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
      ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
      ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
      If .Show = True Then
        TextBox2 = .SelectedItems(1)

      End If
   End With
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
   
    MyVal1 = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value

End Sub


Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    MyVal2 = UserForm1.TextBox2.Value
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

End Sub
```

MODULE 3:

```
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],[MyVal2]Sheet1!R2C1:R5C3,3,FALSE)"
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D7"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("D2:D7").Select
```

Comment: Apologies. I get a Compile error: invalid outside procedure, I think its because its not accepting "myVal2", is it a formatting issue of how i've written it?

Comment: MyVal2 = UserForm1.TextBox2.Value
Thats how I'm storing the sheets name

Comment: Sorry about that. All done now

Comment: Something like `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],[" & MyVal2 & "]Sheet1!R2C1:R5C3,3,FALSE)"`

Comment: Is the code you posted under "MODULE 3:" _All_ the code in Module 3?  If so, you need to wrap it in a `Sub` and call that from somewhere.

Comment: I applied both of your suggestions, I changed my VLOOKUP to yours, wrapped module 3 in a sub, but I don't know where to call it from
I now get an error "run-time error 1004, cannot run the macro Module3.AuscompDataSheet, the macro may not be available in this workbook

Comment: The debugger has issue with this line specifically:

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],[" & MyVal2 & "]Sheet1!R2C1:R5C3,3,FALSE)"

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are assigning the value of the variables myVal1 and MyVal2 by changing the assignment in the CommandButton1 instead of doing it in the textboxes and at the beginning of the code as a public declaration.

```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
      Dim MyVal2, MyVal1 as string
      MyVal2 = UserForm1.TextBox2.Value
      MyVal1 = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
      Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=(MyVal1)
      Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=(MyVal2)
      call AuscompDataSheet
      call AuscompDataSheet
      ActiveWorkbook.Save
      ActiveWorkbook.Close
    End Sub
```

Comment: I don't believe so, as they are declared in order.
The debugger has issue with this line specifically:

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],[" & MyVal2 & "]Sheet1!R2C1:R5C3,3,FALSE)"

Comment: You would have to declare the variable for this code or use the value from the textbox.

Comment: To test, I used your implementations, but the issue doesnt seem to be in the declaration. Your code does the exact same as I'm facing now

Comment: I think in module 3 you should call the AuscompDataSheet process that executes the code with the formula as a function, to pass the variable to the formula. FUNCTION AuscompDataSheet(var as string)

Comment: Could you explain that a bit more indepth sorry? quite new to vba

Comment: If the functions are processes where variables can be transferred, in a form module you cannot transfer the variables to the normal modules, so the most functional thing is to use a function in which you assign a variable and this is recognized within the function, to execute a process with that function, my question is that AuscompDataSheet code in the module that is all that it contains from beginning to end or there is more, pass it in full, to pass it to a function.